# How to transform array to comma separated words string without using implode()

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
    [4] => amet
)
```

How to transform this to a string like this with php?

```
$string = 'lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet';
```

Comment: Why without using `implode()` ???

Comment: Sounds like homework :)

Comment: how about using `join()`? :)

Comment: check this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: It's just matter of using `for` loop, that's what your teacher might be asking you to learn! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = array("1" => "lorem",  
              "2" => "ipsum",
              "3"  => "dolor", 
              "4" => "sit",
              "5" => "amet"
              );



$string = "";       

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
     $string.=$value.",";
}

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use join() - You can use join, its an alias for implode, also more readable:

```
echo join(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="";
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$value){
 $str.=$value.",";
}
rtrim($str, ",");
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

use below solution:

```
<?php
$array = Array
        (
            0 => 'lorem',
            1 => 'ipsum',
            2 => 'dolor',
            3 => 'sit',
            4 => 'amet',
        );

$str = '';

foreach($array as $a){
$str .= $a.', ';
}

echo rtrim($str, ',');
```

**output**

```
lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet
```

Answer (score 1):

using for loop:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'lorem',
    1 => 'ipsum',
    2 => 'dolor',
    3 => 'sit',
    4 => 'amet',
];

$counter = count($array)-1;
$string = '';

 for ($i=0; $i<=$counter; $i++) {
      $string .= $array[$i].', ';
 }

 echo rtrim($string, ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use implode function to convert,a string into array.
Please try this,it will give you the output you want

```
<?php
    $array = Array
        (
            0 => 'lorem',
            1 => 'ipsum',
            2 => 'dolor',
            3 => 'sit',
            4 => 'amet',
        );
    $string = implode(",",$array);
    echo '$string = '."'".$string."'";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and concatenate the items to a string.

Comment: please give example ??